# Upgrading phpMailer from v5.2.7 to v6.8.0

Tags: phpmailer

I am using the latest version of xmapp on windows 11. I want to upgrade my phpMailer to the latest version which is v6.8.0. My current version is v5.2.7 which is really old now.
I have installed phpMailer using composer successfully but I have found a couple of issues I am not sure about. I used the script for site registrations which sends the confirmation email to the clients registering.

The old directorys for my mailer scripts were...

> xampp > htdocs > classes > phpMailer
> mail.php
> scripts
> exception.php
> phpmailer.php
> pop3.php
> smtp.php

The contents of the script mail.php was...

MAIL.PHP

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/classes/phpmailer/scripts/phpmailer.php");
class Mail extends PhpMailer
{
    // Set default variables for all new objects
    public $From     = 'noreply@mydomain.uk';
    public $FromName = 'My Domain Name';
    public $Host     = 'localhost';
    public $Mailer   = 'smtp';
    public $SMTPAuth = false;
    public $Username = 'Username';
    public $Password = 'Password';
    public $SMTPSecure = '';
    public $WordWrap = 75;

    public function subject($subject)
    {
        $this->Subject = $subject;
    }

    public function body($body)
    {
        $this->Body = $body;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        $this->AltBody = strip_tags(stripslashes($this->Body))."\n\n";
        $this->AltBody = str_replace("&nbsp;", "\n\n", $this->AltBody);
        return parent::send();
    }
}
```

The mail.php is triggered by the register.php script in my htdocs folder when a successful registration is made, this is the chunk of code in the register.php script...

REGISTER.PHP

```
        $to = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = "Registration Confirmation";
        $body = "<p>Thank you for registering at My Domain Name.</p>
        <p>To activate your account, please click on this link: <a href='".DIR."activate.php?x=$uname&y=$activasion'>Activate Now</a></p>
        <p>If you did not request to register with Avian Directory then do not click the link, delete this email and the registration request will expire on our site.</p>
        <img src='".DIR."img/logo.png' title='logo' alt='logo' />
        <p>Regards, Site Admin</p>";

        $mail = new Mail();
        $mail->setFrom(SITEEMAIL);
        $mail->addAddress($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->body($body);
        $mail->send();
```

When I installed the new phpMailer using composer, it installed phpMailer to a different directory outside the htdocs folder (xampp/composer/vender/phpmailer) No mail.php file was created.
My questions are, will I need to reconfigure the registration.php email code to work with the new version of phpMailer? also how would I create a new mail.php file to work with the new version of phpMailer? I plan to use TLS instead of a direct connection and I use certificates provided by certbot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [PHPMailer's upgrade guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md)?

The `Mail.php` script is something of your own devising, not part of PHPMailer, so you'll need to create that yourself. The only changes you should need to make are changing this:
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/classes/phpmailer/scripts/phpmailer.php");

to

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; //Adjust for the correct relative path to your vendor folder
```

And this:

```
class Mail extends PhpMailer
```

to

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
class Mail extends PHPMailer
```

Notice the difference in capitalisation - PHP is case-sensitive for class names, so I'm surprised your previous script worked at all.

Comment: I capitalised the mail.php and the register.php only for posting here but they are normal in my scripts and the actual file names are not upper case either. I am just off out for the day now so I will try with your suggestion when I come back. Appreciate your advice, thanks

Comment: Remember that when we see questions on here, we have to take what you say at face value - we can't tell if these are not the actual scripts you are running. [PHP's PSR-4 convention](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) means that it's recommended practice to make the casing of your class names match the names of the files they are in, so a `Mail` class would be expected to be in a file called `Mail.php`.